# Need to use javascript with try,catch and throw exceptions. I want to use it to check a textbox to make sure it is a number not a letter

Tags: javascript, html

When I add the test function it doesn't work. But when I take out the test function it works but still displays any none numbers as `nan`.

HTML code:

```
        <h2>How many male books would you like to order? : <input type="text" id ="maleTotal"/>
        <input type="button" onClick="maleBook()" Value = "Total" />
        <p> The total is: <br>
        <span id = "result"></span></h2>

      </form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function maleBook(){
    var malePrice = 14.95;
    var tax = .06875;
    maleTotal = document.getElementById("maleTotal").value;
    totalTax = tax * malePrice * maleTotal
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = maleTotal * malePrice + totalTax;
}

function test() {
  var x;
  x = document.getElementById("maleTotal").value;
  try { 
    if(x == "") window.alert "empty";
    if(isNaN(x)) window.alert"not a number";
      }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
  }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser inspector?

Comment: Please read how to provide an [mcve].  As-is, your code _does not run_ and will throw errors.

Comment: Adding a linter to your IDE would help.

Comment: May I suggest that you invest in learning some fundamentals: 1. In your browser, when you run javascript, you should use the Developers Tools (google "Chrome Developers Tools").  They will tell you a ton of useful info - in this case, you have typos that are causing the code to not even run.  Second, in order for a function to be useful, you must call the function.  Nowhere in your code do you CALL the `test` function.  Third, your `try - catch` is flawed, and doesn't really do anything.  You are `try`ing valid code, that will always run, so your `catch` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you're missing parenthesis on alerts. It should be like: window.alert("your message");

For another thing, you're missing brackets on if statements {}

Lastly, you need to call the test() function, maybe chain it in at the end of maleBook()

```
function maleBook(){
    var malePrice = 14.95;
    var tax = .06875;
    maleTotal = document.getElementById("maleTotal").value;
    totalTax = tax * malePrice * maleTotal
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = maleTotal * malePrice + totalTax;
    test();
}

function test() {
  var x = document.getElementById("maleTotal").value;
  try { 
    if(x == "") { 
        window.alert( "empty");
    }
    if(isNaN(x)) {
        window.alert("not a number");
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other guys said you are missing the parenthesis at the alerts and a bracket at catch.

I made a change at your javascript code calling test function before you calculate total tax and it became like this.

And it is just a detail but I am passing maleTotal value as a parameter to test function.

```
function maleBook(){
    var malePrice = 14.95;
    var tax = .06875;
    maleTotal = document.getElementById("maleTotal").value;
    if(test(maleTotal)){
        totalTax = tax * malePrice * maleTotal
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = maleTotal * malePrice + totalTax;
    }else{
        //put some message here
    }    
}

function test(x) {
 var err= true;
  try { 
    if(x == ""){
        window.alert("empty");
      err=false;
    } 
    if(isNaN(x)){
        window.alert("not a number");
      err=false;
    }
    return err;
    }catch(err) {
            message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
        return false;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your test function has errors: You are forgetting parethesis next to alert:

alert("some message here");

Also, you dont seem to be calling test(). You sould make test() return true/false depending is the input is a number, and call it in your main function

also "message.innerHTML" doesnt seem to have a meaning here. Just use alert on that as well.